# How much space does mSATA drive take?

Tags: pci-express, msata

I have a board with one mPCIex fullsize and the other one halfsize. I was wondering whether do I need the fullsize slot for mSATA drive or the halfsize slot would suffice ?

The exact drive would be: Adata SSD PremierPro SP300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Premier Pro SP300 [page](http://test.adata-group.com/index.php?action=product_feature&cid=3&piid=182):

> The SP300 is small and light, measuring only 50.95 x 30 x 4mm

This is the [size of a full-sized mPCIe card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Physical_dimensions).

***But***, it's not just slot size you have to worry about: mSATA  is not equal to mPCIe, even though the slots are the same (or at least similar).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Mini_PCI_Express_.26_mSATA):

> Despite sharing the mini-PCI Express form factor, an mSATA slot is not
>   necessarily electrically compatible with Mini PCI Express. For this
>   reason, only certain notebooks are compatible with mSATA drives. Most
>   compatible systems are based on Intel's Sandy Bridge processor
>   architecture, using the Huron River platform. But for a
>   mSATA/mini-PCI-E connector, the only prerequisite is that there is a
>   switch which makes it either a mSATA or a mini-PCI-E slot and can be
>   implemented on any platform.

So whether it will work at all will depend on your motherboard.